# Result and IQArray could not be found

Tags: .net, visual-studio-code, quantum-computing, q#

I am following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/quantum/user-guide/host-programs?tabs=tabid-csharp) MS tutorial to add functionality to my Q#/C#host project.

However, I get two errors on my operations:

```
The type or namespace name 'Result' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [host]csharp(CS0246)

The type or namespace name 'IQArray<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [host]csharp(CS0246)
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you are missing is `using Microsoft.Quantum.Simulation.Core` in your `Program.cs`. Give it a try. It works on my machine.